# How do you deploy build artifacts to Heroku from Codeship?

Tags: heroku, continuous-deployment, codeship

In starting a new project, I put together the skeleton for a Node app that has tests and generates some build artifacts, like asset compilation and compression. I have the tests running in Codeship so successful builds initiate a deploy to Heroku. They've made it all super easy, except I can't find any way to deploy built files, just a copy of what's in the repo.

Has anyone done this successfully? I feel like writing a custom deploy script to rebuild the assets after the tests and manually deploy them would be working against the existing toolset, and I know can't possibly be the first person to want to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that Codeship doesn't keep anything, in fact, different servers do the deployment than the testing. It seems that the best-practice here is to recreate the assets on the Heroku side with a custom [buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks), which, directly after the git pull, does the dependency installation and compiles the app slug.